# How to generate UUID in Realm DB using React Native inside migration?

Tags: react-native, migration, realm, uuid

I'm currently trying to change the primary key for some of my schemas. They used to have an int `id` field but now I want to implement UUID.

Here's my code:

```js
export const realmParams = {
    path: 'db.realm',
    migration: (oldRealm: Realm, newRealm: Realm) => {
        if(oldRealm.schemaVersion <= 34) {
            const allFatherObjects = newRealm.objects('FATHER')
            for (const fatherObject of allFatherObjects) {
                const fatherUuid = new Realm.BSON.UUID()
                fatherObject.uuid = fatherUuid

                const allSonObjectsFromFather = newRealm.objects('SON')
                .filtered(`id_father = ${fatherObject.id_father}`)

                for (let i = 0; i < allSonObjectsFromFather.length; i++) {
                    const sonObject = allSonObjectsFromFather[i]

                    sonObject.uuid = new Realm.BSON.UUID()
                    sonObject.father_uuid = fatherUuid
                }
            }
        }
    },
    schema: [
        FatherSchema,
        SonSchema,
    ],
    schemaVersion: 35,
}
```

But it always returns this error:

```
Exception in HostFunction: Primary key property 'Son.uuid' has duplicate values after migration.
```

I tried to log inside the migration, but nothing appears.

Also, I throw away the primary key property in both schemas to see what was passed and when looking on realm studio every field I fill in with UUID has an empty string.

I've tried to use `uuid.v4` of UUID library from npm (I've already imported the `getRandomValues` into my index) and logging into other classes, I can confirm that it works and it shows me a UUID.

After the migration everything works fine. I am able to generate a new UUID normally and save it in the table, so I assume the problem is just inside the migration function. But I don't want to keep my schemas without a primary key.

What is the problem with generating a UUID on migration and how can I solve it?

In realm version 10, it worked fine. I got the error after updating some libs and one of them is realm. Currently in 11.9.0.

Comment: Just a guess here but if a son appears in more than one fathers list, you're going to end up migrating it twice. It may be better to add uuids to all father objects, and then to all son objects and then iterate over each father's sons and add the father uuid. However, Realm is object based and instead of hard coding uuid's to link a son to a father, how about  for each son object add a father property and add the father object instead of its uuid?

Comment: @Jay I could do that way, even though I know every child has a unique father but do not seem to be the problem. Even if I do not specify a primary key, and the code runs normally that way, when I open realm studio to see what happens on db I see all the uuid fields empty.

Comment: A little off topic; it's not clear from the code as it didn't include your models but the assumption is that a father object contains a List property of sons? - that would be a one to many relationship. If so, then there would not be a reason to also query for the father `.filtered(`id_father = ${fatherObject.id_father}`)` since you're already iterating over them and know the sons because they're contained in the List. When you say 'all the uuid fields empty', which ones - both the fathers and sons? Did you step through the code an examine the vars  along the way to see if you spot an issue?

Comment: Yes, both fields are empty. Father's and son's. They already have the relationship but I want to migrate them to another field. The currently identifier is an integer field called `id` an the new is called `uuid` and is a string. The son will no longer be relate by the older `father_id`, instead it will use `father_uuid` (refering to the new primaryKey of Father).

Comment: If you're relating them via a UUID, that's not really the Realm way to do it. Realm relationships are generated via the object itself, not its uuid or _id. I know that doesn't address the question but may add some clarity going forward.

Comment: The error is because the first Son object has a blank primary key, and so no others can have that (primary keys must be unique) - but your code attempts to set the second son to blank (and the next and the next) hence the error. So, if you  'throw away' the primary key property (as mentioned in the question), then the query in the migration won't find anything and all of the object UUID's will remain blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the field `migration` from realm config object changed to `onMigration`. That explain why no logs could be saw, or breakpoints don't stop the code inside the function. Realm simply wasn't executing the migration. Also explain why all fields that I created was blank after removing uuid from the schemas.

They probably forgot of update the docs.

The new code:

```js
export const realmParams = {
    path: 'db.realm',
    onMigration: (oldRealm: Realm, newRealm: Realm) => {
        if(oldRealm.schemaVersion <= 34) {
            const allFatherObjects = newRealm.objects('FATHER')
            for (const fatherObject of allFatherObjects) {
                const fatherUuid = new Realm.BSON.UUID()
                fatherObject.uuid = fatherUuid

                const allSonObjectsFromFather = newRealm.objects('SON')
                .filtered(`id_father = ${fatherObject.id_father}`)

                for (let i = 0; i < allSonObjectsFromFather.length; i++) {
                    const sonObject = allSonObjectsFromFather[i]

                    sonObject.uuid = new Realm.BSON.UUID()
                    sonObject.father_uuid = fatherUuid
                }
            }
        }
    },
    schema: [
        FatherSchema,
        SonSchema,
    ],
    schemaVersion: 35,
}
```